# Hijri date with gregorian date

Tags: vb.net

thank you for resolving the errors from the programmers here

I want to display the Hijri date with the Gregorian date in the label

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'Put user code to initialize the page here
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
BINDSEC()
Textbox1.Text = Request.QueryString("prompt0")
RDate = CDate(Request.QueryString("prompt1"))
CCDate = CDate(Request.QueryString("prompt2"))
d3 = Request.QueryString("prompt3")
d4 = Request.QueryString("prompt4")
'  d5 = 1

```
    End If
    Execute()

End Sub
```